# How to make char array available in multiple .cpp files?

Tags: c++, class, scope, global-variables

I have a working program which must be split into multiple parts, for edition purposes. This program is needed to keep user login info in char arrays to be able to connect to SQL, and this connection info is used many times in parts of the program that will end up in separated .cpp files, which will compile in a single program.

The problem is that if they are declared in just one file, they will be missing in the rest, and if they are declared in all of them, there will be duplicated definitions.

So, to make a concrete and simple example, if I have the following code:

```
#include <mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace mysqlpp;

char server[]   =   "localhost";
char user[]     =   "root";
char pass[]     =   "xxxxxxx";
char db[]       =   "prog";

void function()
    {
    Connection con;
    con.connect("", server, user, pass);
    con.select_db(db);
    //action1...;
    }

void separated_function()
    {
    Connection con;
    con.connect("", server, user, pass);
    con.select_db(db);
    //action2...;
    }

int
main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    cout << "INICIO\n";

    function();
    separated_function();
    //something else with the mentioned variables...;
    
    cout << "FIN\n";
    return 0;
}
```

How can it be split correctly, to have `function()`, `another_function()` and `main()` in separated .cpp files,and make `server`, `user`, `pass` and `db` avaliable to all of them.

I know there must be many ways, but any working one is good enough, since I'm not getting any results so far.

**NOTE: This question is not about how to use the variables with MySQL, but how to split the program correctly.**

Comment: `sqlcon.server   =   "localhost";` You cannot do this outside of a function. Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: so that's the problem? I'm trying to use something that must be inside a function?

Comment: That's at least one definite problem I can spot from the code you have posted. Can't tell anything about the rest. Also `char server[];` might be problematic, I'd recommend to use `std::string` instead.

Comment: That was the current code I was trying to use... would you recommend to better remove it from the question?

Comment: No, you should post a minimal sample that reproduces all of your errors in question, also post those error messages verbatim.

Comment: Ok, I changed the question almost completely, to make my point clearer. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Do not use global variables. Put the required state into a struct or class, and pass it to functions as necessary as a parameter.

Comment: @NeilKirk, I tried it previously, but I messed it up (I'm a newbie, LOL). That's why I posted this concrete example, so someone could split it the correct way. But thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `extern` in the seperated source files, or in a common header that is included in the seperated source files. You will define them in one (and only one) cpp file. Here is an example:

main.h

```
void function();
void seperated_function();

namespace myGlobals {
  extern char server[];
  extern char user[];
  extern char pass[];
  extern char db[];
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"

namespace myGlobals {
  char server[] = "localhost";
  char user[] = "root";
  char pass[] = "xxxxxxx";
  char db[] = "prog";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << "main.cpp\n";
  std::cout << myGlobals::server << "\n";
  std::cout << myGlobals::user << "\n";
  std::cout << myGlobals::pass << "\n";
  std::cout << myGlobals::db << "\n\n";
  function();
  seperated_function();
  return 0;
}
```

function.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"

void function() {
  std::cout << "function.cpp\n";
  std::cout << myGlobals::server << "\n";
  std::cout << myGlobals::user << "\n";
  std::cout << myGlobals::pass << "\n";
  std::cout << myGlobals::db << "\n\n";
}
```

seperated_function.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"

void seperated_function() {
  std::cout << "seperated function.cpp\n";
  std::cout << myGlobals::server << "\n";
  std::cout << myGlobals::user << "\n";
  std::cout << myGlobals::pass << "\n";
  std::cout << myGlobals::db << "\n\n";
}
```

The `namespace myGlobals` is not required, but if I am going to use global variables I at least like to put them in their own namespace.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the answer I was especting :) .
I adapted this to my code and works fine.

Comment: @Fahedsl You're welcome. Please accept this answer since it appears to have provided the solution for you.

Comment: And it also worked perfectly for some GTK+ variables. But now I'm really curious about what @NeilKirk said: "Do not use global variables. Put the required state into a struct or class, and pass it to functions as necessary as a parameter."

Comment: Yes, it is best to avoid global variables. I'm sure if you search you will find many discussions on the subject.

Comment: You made a clear answer (to what I think is a clear question), so I invite you to read [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730915/how-to-make-a-variable-avaliable-to-multiple-cpp-files-using-a-class/32731057?noredirect=1#comment53304342_32731057) derived from this one. And if it is posible to you, give an answer.

Comment: @Fahedsl I don't know if I would have much to add to the answers already given. GIve me a few and I'll see if I can come up with another example, if you like.